# Dropdown different size problem html css survey form

Tags: html, css

[https://codepen.io/nkalandadze/pen/GRNOrqY ]

Dropdown is a different size,

Can you help please ?

thanks <3

Comment: Please don't post your code as links, put the actual code text in your question. Also, please clarify what you mean by "Dropdown is a different size".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

If you are newer to html and css I would recommend bootstrap because it takes care of a lot of the work for you and helps eliminate weird space issues once you get the hang of it. Its as easy as adding divs and classes to the elements. I didn't even have to touch css.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="row my-4 mx-5"> 
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <select class="form-select" name="choice" aria-label="Floating label select example" required>
                            <option value="bad" selected>Choose One</option>
                            <option value="user">Test</option>
                            <option value="computer">Test 2</option>           
                         </select>
                         <label for="choice">Choose Ticket Type</label>
                     </div>
                 </div>
         
                 <div class="row my-4 mx-5"> 
                     <div class="form-floating">
                         <select class="form-select" name="choice" aria-label="Floating label select example" required>
                             <option value="bad" selected>Choose One</option>
                             <option value="user">Test</option>
                             <option value="computer">Test 2</option>           
                          </select>
                         <label for="choice">Choose Ticket Type</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
         
                  <div class="row my-4 mx-5"> 
                      <div class="form-floating">
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="a" name="date_added">
                      </div>
                  </div>
         
                  <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      <div class="d-grid gap-1 col-6">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>  
                      </div>
                  </div><br>
             </form>
         </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```